# How to do symbolic links for localhost?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, stores

I need to create the new store using this tutorial: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/

symbolic links, how can I do on windows localhost?

```
ln -s ../your-new-website/app ./app
ln -s ../your-new-website/errors ./errors
ln -s ../your-new-website/includes ./includes
ln -s ../your-new-website/js ./js
ln -s ../your-new-website/lib ./lib
ln -s ../your-new-website/media ./media
ln -s ../your-new-website/skin ./skin
ln -s ../your-new-website/var ./var
```

Comment: you can create shortcut in windows

Comment: https://snag.gy/MhSlDu.jpg  still not working, after created shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, you can create symbolic links from the command line using the following:

```
mklink ..\your-new-website\app app
```

Comment: few error, after crate symbolic link can't navigate into that folder, and some other system getting an error like, "Access is denied" even if i open cmd as a administrator.

Comment: after created symbolic links why i cant able go to the folder https://snag.gy/AO5ovI.jpg